# ¿Cómo detener un timer después de 10 segundos en Java?

Tags: java, funciones, timer

Quiero que al llegar mi variable `count` a 10 se detenga el tiempo para ejecutar otra acción.

```
public TimerTask tiempoEjecucion() {

    TimerTask _timerTask;
    _timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            System.out.println(count++);
        }
    };

    return _timerTask;
}

public void iniciarTiempo() {
    int count = 0;
    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tiempoEjecucion(), 0, 1000);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    iniciarTiempo();
}
```

El Problema es que no logro detener el tiempo, básicamente este codigo servira para un `JProgressBar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que agregar la condición de parada del `TimerTask` en el método `run()` y si se cumple llamas a `cancel()`.

```
_timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count == 10) {
            cancel();
        }
        System.out.println(count++);
    }
};
```

Comment: intente hacerlo con un `while` pero el formulario no habria hasta terminar el bucle

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un contador puedes usar el método [cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--) para cancelar el timer task cuando el contador llegue a 10.

```
_timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        if(count == 10) cancel();               
        System.out.println(count++);
    }
};
```

Además, esto lo puedes realizar también usando la clase [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), defines cada cuantos segundos se llamara y al contar 10 segundos puedes detener el servicio mediante el método [shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) :

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = null;

public TimerTask tiempoEjecucion() {

    TimerTask _timerTask;
    _timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        int count = 1;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Han transcurrido " + count + " segundos.");
            if (count >= 10) {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
            count++;
        }
    };

    return _timerTask;
}

public void iniciarTiempo() {
    executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(tiempoEjecucion(), 1 /*Retardo inicial*/, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Cada 1 segundo
}
```

Salida:

```
Han transcurrido 1 segundos.
Han transcurrido 2 segundos.
Han transcurrido 3 segundos.
Han transcurrido 4 segundos.
Han transcurrido 5 segundos.
Han transcurrido 6 segundos.
Han transcurrido 7 segundos.
Han transcurrido 8 segundos.
Han transcurrido 9 segundos.
Han transcurrido 10 segundos.
```